# Apply jquery script to only woocommerce product pages and categories

Tags: functions, jquery, javascript, woocommerce-offtopic

I have this script that automatically scrolls down to the primary content on page load.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  if ( $(window).width() < 768 || window.Touch) { 
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#primary").offset().top}, 2000);} 
});
```

**1.** However I would like to *only* apply it to our woocommerce product pages and categories so it doesnt work on home/blog pages. How would i do that?

I can do this *poorly* by editing WooCommerce core files but i know that's a horrible idea so I'm seeking out help on how to do it correctly via my functions.php file.

**2.** Also i would like to know how to apply it to all pages except the home page should that be a better option later on.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways you could do that.

## 1. Using JS only

WordPress themes normally use the [`body_class()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/) function. As a result you'll see that the `<body>` tag will have lots of classes. You can then target pages with a specific class to run your code in JavaScript:

```
if( $('body.whateverclass').length || $('body.anotherclass').length ){
   // Your JS code here
}
```

## 2. Using PHP

You can harness [`wp_localize_script()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to send a flag to your code.

Let's suppose you enqueued a file called `site.js` with a handle name of `site`, in your `functions.php` you'll have:

```
wp_register_script( 'site', 'path/to/site.js' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'site' );
```

You can now add some flags:

```
 wp_register_script( 'site', 'path/to/site.js' ); # Unchanged

 $value = '';
 if ( is_shop() || is_some_other_condition() ){
    $value = 'yes';
 }
 wp_localize_script( 'site', 'MYSITE', $value );

 wp_enqueue_script( 'site' ); # Unchanged
```

You can then check the `MYSITE` variable in JavaScript:

```
if( 'yes' === MYSITE ){
  // Your JS code here
}
```

Edit:
[You asked](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/259987/apply-jquery-script-to-only-woocommerce-product-pages-and-categories/259996#comment385846_259996) how to put it in the footer.php:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  if( $('body.product-template-default').length || $('body.anotherclass').length ){
    if ( $(window).width() < 768 || window.Touch) { 
         $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#primary").offset().top}, 2000); 
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: If im using js.. How would that look exactly? I put this at the bottom of my footer.php and cant get it to work. (works without the if statement) 

<script>
  if( $('body.product-template-default').length || $('body.anotherclass').length ){
   jQuery(document).ready(function($){
              if ( $(window).width() < 768 || window.Touch) { 
                  $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#primary").offset().top}, 2000);
              } 
          });
}
</script>

Comment: @PortalP Updated my answer with your code. the `jQuery(document)....` part should be outermost.

Comment: Thanks! although for some reason i cant get it to work. :(

Comment: Nvm i got it to work! :) THANKS! This is gonna be so useful in so many situations.

Comment: My screen width script isnt working. its only suppose to work on widths smaller than 768px or smaller. Is it okay that an if statement is inside another? Should they not be combined as one if statement?

Thanks!

Comment: No problem about putting `if` inside another. What's the purpose of your script? From what I can read, it should scroll to the `#primary` element each time you load the page while the screen width is less than 768.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not available for free private debugging sessions :) Remove the `|| window.Touch` and try again. Or try StackOverflow for non WordPress related issues.

Comment: @RRikesh what's the difference between `site` and `some_handle`? I would think that after registering `site`, we now enqueue it.. but apparently something else was enqueued

Comment: @MalcolmSalvador I guess you're right. No idea how that typo slipped in.

Answer (score 3):

Step 1: save the code as a new js file, say main.js

Step 2: add a conditional function to function.php of your theme that would say something around the lines:

```
if (is_shop() || is_product_category()) {
  wp_enqueue_script('main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', false, false, true);
}
```

Check this page for conditional tags based on your needs:

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/

Hope it helps!

Edit:

For inline scripting you could do (e.g. inside footer.php):

```
if (is_shop() || is_product_category()) {?>
      <script>
          jQuery(document).ready(function($){
              if ( $(window).width() < 768 || window.Touch) { 
                  $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#primary").offset().top}, 2000);
              } 
          });
      </script>
<?php}
```

Comment: Thanks! But how can i add the script inline? I feel like creating an additional call to a script file is pointless when the script itself (provided above) is tiny.

Comment: I guess you could use the exact same IF statement in the footer.php but instead of enqueueing you could write your script inside <script> tags but I do not recommend it, especially for jQuery scripts.

Comment: Why not? Also can you update that answer with an example snippet?

Comment: I've updated the answer.